# Select from 2 table and get a filed from table alia

Tags: mysql

i have this code to select from table join another table and working fine but i want in return response in array select a filed from table alia
i want this  "value"=>$row->item_name  to be "value"=>$row->itbl.item_name

```
        $this->db->from('items_tbl as itbl');
        $this->db->join('items_description as ids',"itbl.item_barcode =ids.item_barcode ",'inner');
        $this->db->where("itbl.item_new_barcode like '%".$postData['search']."%' ");
        $this->db->group_by('itbl.item_new_barcode');
       $records = $this->db->get()->result();

       foreach($records as $row ){
          $response[] = array(
              "id"=>$row->item_id,
              "value"=>$row->item_name,
              "label"=>$row->item_new_barcode,
              "instore"=>$row->item_quantity,
              "expdate"=>$row->item_exp_date,
              "newbarcode"=>$row->item_new_barcode);
       }
```

Comment: this error  
ERROR - 2021-07-05 18:33:33 --> Severity: Notice --> Trying to get property 'item_name' of non-object

Answer (score 1):

```
$this->db->from('items_tbl');
    $this->db->select('items_tbl.item_id,items_description.item_name,items_tbl.item_new_barcode,items_tbl.item_exp_date,items_tbl.item_quantity as q');
    $this->db->join('items_description ',"items_tbl.item_barcode =items_description.item_barcode ",'inner');
    $this->db->where("items_tbl.item_new_barcode like '%".$postData['search']."%' ");
    $this->db->group_by('items_tbl.item_new_barcode');
   $records = $this->db->get()->result();

   foreach($records as $row ){
      $response[] = array(
          "id"=>$row->item_id,
          "value"=>$row->item_name,
          "label"=>$row->item_new_barcode,
          "instore"=>$row->q,
          "expdate"=>$row->item_exp_date,
          "newbarcode"=>$row->item_new_barcode);
   }
```